# Как разрешить доступ для определенного запроса?

Tags: spring-boot, angular, spring-security

у меня есть клиент на angular и backend на Spring Boot.
конфиг выглядит следующим образом

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private JwtFilter jwtFilter;
@Override


protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("*/api/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("*/api/user/*").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/register", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

Если я уберу *, то ни один запрос с клиента не работает (ошибка 403)
Со *, не работает метод hasRole делает запрос на любой api например /order, а на /order/1 опять та же ошибка . Как это починить?